# Unable to find a user after creation

Tags: python, sql

Python on an IQ Database

```
 try:
            cursor.execute("""CREATE USER Craig IDENTIFIED BY Xxxxx12345;""")
            self.logger.info("Add a user")
 except Exception as e:
            self.logger.warning("Exception:", e)

try:
            rows_count = cursor.execute("""Select count(*) from dbo.sysusers where name = 'Craig';""")
            if rows_count and rows_count > 0:
                self.logger.info("User was found")
            else:
                self.logger.info("User was not found")
except:
            blah blah blah
```

If I check the database, I can see that the user is there. If I try to add it again, it says it already exists. If I drop the user programmatically, it is successful because I can go back to the database and see that the user has been removed.

What I want to have happen is one row is returned so I see if the value of rows_count > 0 then that means I found the exact user I was just created.

Comment: I don't think `execute()`  will return the count number directly -- it returns the _rows_ that match the query.  (Although if that is true, then you should have gotten a TypeError exception because you can't compare a list to an integer).  Try printing `rows_count` to see what type it is.

Comment: I did get the TypeError exception so I added the rows_count and rows_count > 0.  Trying to figure how I can get a number back

Comment: I think I should be able to fetch through that list.

Comment: It should be a list of one row, and the row should have the count value as its first item, so `rows_count[0][0]` should be the value you're looking for.

Comment: New error:  (TypeError("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"),)

Comment: @JohnGordon I was able to see that rows_count was None. Based on what you said, I was able to figure out how to resolve the issue. 
        result_set=cursor.fetchall()
        row_count=len(result_set)
       
        if row_count == 1:
            try:
                self.logger.info("User was found")